# js setInterval is working but setTimeout isn't

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I'm learning about setTimeout vs setInterval and I have got setInterval to work but not setTimeout.  for example this doesnt work:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Brewery</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function doNothing()
        {
            var t = "hello wolrd";
        }

        function poll(){
        $.ajax({
            //url: "http://192.168.0.11/"+Math.random(),
            url:"line-ajax.htm",
            contentType:"text/html",
            success: 'doNothing()'
        });
        }

        setTimeout(poll(),2000);
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.highcharts.com/highslide/highslide.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 1200px; height: 500px; margin: 0 auto"></div>             
    </body>
</html>
```

but if i change only this

```
setTimeout(poll(),2000);
```

to

```
setInterval(poll(),2000);
```

it will make an ajax request every 2 seconds...

what is going on?

---edit
i have also tried `setTimeout(poll,2000);` but that doesn't make the ajax request every 2 sec either.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message, or...? With your code as shown, both `setTimeout(poll(),2000)` and `setInterval(poll(),2000)` should make the ajax request exactly once, and make it immediately, because you are calling the `poll()` function immediately and passing its return (undefined) to `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()`.

Comment: i should have been more specific with what I mean by doesn't work sorry.  I'm trying to get setTimeout to call the 'poll' function every 2 seconds, it is not.  But set setInterval(poll(),2000); does call the poll function every 2 secs.  Im trying to understand why.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "I'm trying to get setTimeout to call the 'poll' function every 2 seconds, it is not"

The [`.setTimeout()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) calls the function you pass it exactly once, after the specified delay.

The [`.setInterval()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) calls the function you pass it repeatedly, with the specified delay between each call.

From the update to your question you seem to think they both do the same thing. Please read the doco I've linked to.

Note that you have to pass a function reference (or a string to be eval'd), so say:

```
setInterval(poll, 2000);
// NOT
setInterval(poll(), 2000);
```

The latter should not work because it calls `poll()` immediately and passes its return value (`undefined`) to `setInterval()`, so I really can't understand why it worked for you.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the `()` inside the `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Treat the function name as a variable, and that's what you're passing.

Comment: How can you be certain it isn't working? Your code doesn't seem to do much at the given interval.  Do you have firebug? if so check the net tab to see if your XHR is running.

Comment: I'm looking for the http get requests in httpfox.  I have firebug when I put a break point on the 'function poll(){' line it only breaks on it once when using setTimeout.  The response http header has status 200

Comment: @cobolstinks - If you are using `setTimout()` it is only supposed to call the function once. Did you read [the doco](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout)? If you want it to be called repeatedly then use `setInterval()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn ty i think you got it.  setTimeout is only a one time event, whereas setInterval is a continual firing.  Duh guess setInterval is the tool i need not setTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

As the parameter of setTimeout is eval'd you should try this:

```
setTimeout("poll()",2000);
```

Or if you like to work with anonymous functions better than with strings that get eval'd:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  poll();
},2000);
```

I personally like the latter more.

Comment: @bardir - you can also say `setTimeout(poll, 2000)` - no need for the anonymous function unless you need to pass parameters to `poll()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to `setTimeout()` should be a reference to the function to be called, not a function call with `()`. So try:

```
setTimeout(poll, 2000);
//-----------^^^
// No parentheses...
```

Likewise, in the `$.ajax()` call, the `success` function should be a function pointer, not a string:

```
$.ajax({
        //url: "http://192.168.0.11/"+Math.random(),
        url:"line-ajax.htm",
        contentType:"text/html",
        // Function pointer to doNothing
        success: doNothing
  });
```

Comment: Actually, i think jQuery will handle a string just fine there, you can even pass an array of functions into the success event. Haven't tried it tho' as it would not explain why setInterval is working while setTimeout isn't.